# Laravel 5.5 Queue Job doesn't respect timeout

Tags: heroku, laravel-5, rabbitmq

I have a job in Laravel 5.5 that doesn't respect the value in the variable `public $timeout` set on the job as described in the [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues#time-based-attempts).

If I set the value of $timeout to, for example, 120 seconds I would expect the job to be terminated after it has ran for 120 seconds. I'm using [RabbitMQ](https://github.com/vyuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq) on a [Heroku dyno](https://www.heroku.com/dynos).

**Codebase**:
Laravel 5.5

**Extension**:
RabbitMQ Queue driver for Laravel

**Platform**:
Heroku dyno (Amazon).

**Example code**:

```
class ExampleJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $timeout = 120;

    public function handle()
    {
        DB::statement($this->buildCallStatement());
    }
}
```

**Example Procfile**:

```
worker: php artisan queue:listen rabbitmq --queue=high,medium,low --tries=1 --memory=512 --timeout=0
```

Answer (score 0):

On your example command you are setting a timeout of 0 which is likely overriding your member variable. Also, setting a timeout of 0 can be dangerous and may cause an infinite loop.

Comment: From Laravel docs: "If the timeout is specified on the job, it will take precedence over any timeout specified on the command line:"